# actionScript isn't working correctly

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to let the animation play to a frame that is linked to a certain number and I figuered out this code but it isn't working can someone explain why it isn't working?

```
    var cijfer_txt = int(textarea_text);

switch (cijfer_txt){
    case 1:
    gotoAndStop(12);
    break;
    case 2:
    gotoAndStop(23);
    break;      }
```

thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

It looks mostly fine to me syntax-wise, but I'll take a bit of a guess and assume that "textarea_text" refers to a text area object. You probably want the contents of the text area object there instead. Try going:

```
var cijfer_txt:int = parseInt(textarea_text.text);
```

Other things you could do to check what is going on is to trace out the actual value of "cijfer_txt" just to see what it really is.

Comment: thanks for the reply the textarea_text is a text area object and and cijfer = dutch for number, but I tried the code and it is still not working. I type this code in the actionscript of a button so maybe that is the clue, my animation is only coded with stop(); ???

Comment: maybe I schould add an onMouseClickEvent??

Comment: I'm not sure where your code is or what you mean by 'actionscript of a button'. However, put in a trace() call and see what you're getting as well as When it is being printed. You probably don't want it to run right away when there is no text in the text area? Note that a blank string will turn in to NaN (not a number) when parsed by parseInt(). If you're getting this, then it should be obvious as to what is going on.

Comment: this is my code right now: var cijfer_txt:int = parseInt(textarea_text.text);

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

submit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
 switch (cijfer){
 case 1:
 gotoAndStop(12);
 break;
 case 2:
 gotoAndStop(23);
 break;  }

}

Comment: Never worked with TouchEvents, but it looks ok to me.