# how to use switch() in a touchevent

Tags: actionscript-3, touch, switch-statement

I'm trying to let the animation play to a frame that is linked to a certain number what someone has entered and I figuered out this code but it isn't working can someone explain why it isn't working?

```
var cijfer_txt = int(textarea_text);

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

submit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    switch (cijfer){
    case 1:
    gotoAndStop(12);
    break;
    case 2:
    gotoAndStop(23);
    break;      }

}
```

thanks for the reply

Comment: If you only want to use single point touch events, you can simply use mouse events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [actionScript isn't working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617105/actionscript-isnt-working-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, two potential reasons I can see here.

1. The first thing is that you are defining the "cijfer_txt" only once when this code first runs. You need to break this line and shift it into the handler to make it run each time the tap function runs. Also, is "textarea_text" correct? If "textarea_text" is the name of the text input box, you need to use "textarea_text.text" to retrieve the value.
2. The next thing is that you are using a variable by the name of "cijfer" in the switch statement but defining the number as "cijfer_txt".

Try this code and see if it works for you (untested as I'm not on my PC now):

```
var cijfer_txt:int;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
submit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    cijfer_txt = int(textarea_text); // Check textarea_text shouldn't be textarea_text.text
    switch (cijfer_txt){
    case 1:
        gotoAndStop(12);
    break;
    case 2:
        gotoAndStop(23);
    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply sorry about the "textarea_text" it should be "textarea_text.text" as you said, further more I copied you're code changed the "textarea_text", tested it in flash but it didn't work, the animation still doesn't do anything... maybe it is because I'm using flash cs5.5, I use this code to make an application in air for Android otherwise I don't get the clue....

Comment: Hmm... that's odd. Try putting some traces about the code and seeing if the function does actually run.
So, stick a "trace(typeof(cijfer_txt), cijfer_txt)" after "cijfer_txt = int(textarea_text.text)" and seeing what we get.

Comment: I put it like this cijfer_txt = int(textarea_text.text); trace(typeof(cijfer_txt), cijfer_txt); press Ctrl+Enter but still the same happens I can fill in a number I can press the button but nothing happens

Comment: So, the output window is not showing anything? That would mean that the functions isn't running, so it is probably the event listener not firing for some reason...
Edit: I've just realised if you are testing on a tablet or mobile device there may be no trace window.
`switch (cijfer_txt){
case 1:
    gotoAndStop(12);
break;
case 2:
    gotoAndStop(23);
break;
default:
    gotoAndStop(<some other easily identifiable frame>);
}`
If we goto the other frame, then we'll know whether the handler _is_ being called or not.

Comment: Hi I saw you answer on a other question of me so thank you very much there for I only don't really get it because the animation of part one has to stop at the last frame of part one but now it continues, you answer dissapeared in some way so I'm happy I copied it but I changed the text you added so I don't know what I schould type in for that. maybe you could answer it again or explain  what the meanings are of the numbers of frames I schould insert Thanks...

Comment: Well, I can if you want. I deleted it as after I'd posted it, I realised it said "jQuery" and thought perhaps I was being silly and not reading the whole question, but I'll put it back up for you.