# why is this script in as3 not working??

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I made this code and I use flash cs5.5

```
var cijfer_txt:int = parseInt(textarea_text.text);

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

submit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{

    switch (cijfer_txt){
    case 1:
    gotoAndStop(12);
    break;
    case 2:
    gotoAndStop(23);
    break;      }

};
```

but I don't get it why it isn't working, the animation has to go to frame 12 when I fill in "1" and stop and has to got to frame 23 if I fill in "2" and stop but he doesn't do it and I get sick of it!!

Comment: This is the second time you have posted with the same code and a non-descriptive subject line. "Why is this script not working?" is not a good question. It's time to learn some debugging and troubleshooting skills to track down your problem, just as every other programmer does. If your switch variable isn't producing the results you expect, trace it's value to ensure the value itself is what you expect. Learn how to use the debugger and traces to help you track this down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [actionScript isn't working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617105/actionscript-isnt-working-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set cijfer_txt in fl_TapHandler_2

```
function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{

    cijfer_txt = parseInt(textarea_text.text);

    switch (cijfer_txt){

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but this doesn't work either, my animation doesn't start, maybe it is because I have put stop(); in the actions code of the animation so it wouldn't loop but otherwise I really don't get the clue why it isn't working

Comment: is fl_TapHandler_2 been called?

Comment: Debug and set breakpoint in fl_TapHandler_2  or just trace something in fl_TapHandler_2  .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with debugging so I'll help you:

First: change your code as follows -

```
var cijfer_txt:int;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

submit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    cijfer_txt = parseInt(textarea_text.text);
    trace("in the function, cijfer_txt = "+cijfer_txt);
    switch (cijfer_txt) {
       case 1:
         trace("in case 1");
         gotoAndStop(12);
         break;
       case 2:
         trace("in case 2");
         gotoAndStop(23);
         break;
       default:
         trace("in defaukt");
         break;
      }
}
```

NOW RUN IT AND WATCH THE CONSOLE\OUTPUT FOR TRACE OUTPUTS,
according to the output you can see what is hapening!
trace(); is a very common method
Good Luck
(Don't forget to mark as accepted if it helped you!)